# Account Documents

Tags: soql, contentdocumentlink

I am using the following SOQL query to get the documents attached to an account:

```
select LinkedEntityId    
, ContentDocument.Title
, ContentDocument.ContentSize
,ContentDocument.Description
, ContentDocument.FileExtension
, ContentDocument.FileType
, ContentDocument.Id 
, ContentDocument.ContentAssetId
, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData
, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.PathOnClient
,ContentDocument.CreatedBy.Name
  FROM ContentDocumentLink
WHERE LinkedEntityId in (SELECT Id from Account where id='0014W00002nVX2KQAW')
```

I need to include the account Name in the result. How can I join to the account table? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the [TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) clause. Given that the `LinkedEntityId` is a polymorphic field you need to specify the fields you want to retrieve depending on the LinkedEntity `sObjectType`.

For your particular scenario, in which you want to retrieve the Name of the Account, your query should be updated to:

```
[
SELECT 
TYPEOF LinkedEntity WHEN Account THEN Name END,
LinkedEntityId, 
ContentDocument.Title,
ContentDocument.ContentSize,
ContentDocument.Description,
ContentDocument.FileExtension,
ContentDocument.FileType,
ContentDocument.Id,
ContentDocument.ContentAssetId,
ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData,
ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.PathOnClient,
ContentDocument.CreatedBy.Name
FROM 
ContentDocumentLink
WHERE 
LinkedEntityId IN 
(SELECT Id from Account where id='0014W00002nVX2KQAW')
]
```

Best regards!